# Similar to Pass in Python for C#

Tags: c#, python

In python we can ...

```
a = 5
if a == 5:
    pass #Do Nothing
else:
    print "Hello World"
```

Is there a similar way to do this in C#?

Answer (score 48):

Use empty braces.

```
int a = 5;
if (a == 5) {}
else {
  Console.Write("Hello World");
}
```

Comment: This solution is non-optimal as you can't set a breakpoints "inside" the braces.

Comment: @cic You can set breakpoints to the line with the closing braces (or to the line with the opening braces if it's on a single line), which both semantically corresponds exactly to "inside" the braces.

Answer (score 16):

In case you don't want to use empty block, use

```
;
```

so the code should look like

```
int a = 5;
if (a == 5)
  ;
else 
{
  Console.Write("Hello World");
}
```

although, code readability still suffer.

Answer (score 13):

Why not just say:

```
if (a != 5) 
{
   Console.Write("Hello World");
}
```

Comment: This is also the way I would recommend it.

Comment: Yeah except it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 12):

Empty block:

```
{}
```

Answer (score 6):

Is `pass` used in the context of a loop? If so, use the `continue` statement:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    if (i == 5)
    {
        continue;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
}
```

Comment: `pass` and `continue` are not the same in python and thus you cannot use `continue` in C# everywhere you mean `{}` aka `do nothing`.

Answer (score 5):

Either use an empty block as suggested in other answers, or reverse the condition:

```
if (a != 5)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
}
```

or more mechanically:

```
if (!(a == 5))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Why make it easy when you could do it unnecessarily difficult?

```
((Action) (() => { }))();
```

On a serious note, the C# equivalent of the Python pass statement would be

```
;
```

since it's a line of code that does nothing. While

```
{}
```

would achieve the same result, you're actually creating a scope containing no lines of code.

Answer (score 3):

A better question would be why you would want to do such a thing.  If you're not planning on doing anything then leave it out, rather.

```
int a = 5;
if (a != 5) {
    Console.Write("Hello World");
}
```